# MySQL queries testing WHERE clause search times

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization, where-clause

Recently I was pulled into the boss-man's office and told that one of my queries was slowing down the system. I then was told that it was because my `WHERE` clause began with `1 = 1`. In my script I was just appending each of the search terms to the query so I added the `1 = 1` so that I could just append `AND` before each search term. I was told that this is causing the query to do a full table scan before proceeding to narrow the results down.

I decided to test this. We have a `user` table with around 14,000 records. The queries were ran five times each using both phpmyadmin and PuTTY. In phpmyadmin I limited the queries to 500 but in PuTTY there was no limit. I tried a few different basic queries and tried clocking the times on them. I found that the `1 = 1` seemed to cause the query to be faster than just a query with no `WHERE` clause at all. This is on a live database but it seemed the results were fairly consistent.

I was hoping to post on here and see if someone could either break down the results for me or explain to me the logic for either side of this.
[image]

Comment: If your results show faster result then it should be no problem, have you analyzed data where it is slowing it down? what did you use to clock the time?

Comment: I'm more curious to see what people think about using 1 = 1 in the WHERE clause. You're right though, from my results it does appear to be faster-which makes me happy-but I'd like maybe some justification. In either program, after the query ran it would say "Query took x seconds." I assumed that would suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, your boss-man and his information source are both idiots.  Adding `1=1` to a query does not cause a full table scan.  The only thing it does is make query parsing take a miniscule amount longer.  Any decent query plan generator (including the mysql one) will realize this condition is a NOP and drop it.

I tried this on my own database (solar panel historical data), nothing interesting out of the noise.

```
mysql> select sum(KWHTODAY) from Samples where Timestamp >= '2010-01-01';
seconds: 5.73, 5.54, 5.65, 5.95, 5.49
mysql> select sum(KWHTODAY) from Samples where Timestamp >= '2010-01-01' and 1=1;
seconds: 6.01, 5.74, 5.83, 5.51, 5.83
```

Note I used ajreal's query cache disabling.

Comment: `Well, your boss-man and his information source are both idiots` - I lol'd

Answer (score 1):

First at all, did you `set session query_cache_type=off;` during both testing?

Secondly, both your testing queries on PHPmyadmin and Putty (mysql client) are so different, how to verify?
You should apply same query on both site.

Also, you can not assume PHPmyadmin is query cache off. The time display on the phpmyadmin is including PHP processing, which you should avoid as well.

Therefore, you should just do the testing on mysql client instead.

Comment: That's interesting. It seemed to indeed make the 'WHERE 1 = 1' query take longer than the clause-less query, but there is still no noticeable change between "WHERE 1 = 1 AND `firstName` = 'David'" and just "WHERE `firstName` = 'David'".

Comment: I do not think both are difference, main suspect is did not turn off the query cache

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a really accurate way to determine what's going on inside MySQL. Things like caching and network variations could skew your results.

You should look into using "explain" to find out what query plan MySQL is using for your queries with and without your 1=1. A DBA will be more interested in those results. Also, if your 1=1 is causing a full table scan, you will know for sure.

The explain syntax is here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html

How to interpret the results are here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain-output.html

Comment: Those are very good points. I'll take a look at using explain to try to see what is going on. I'm still hoping someone can shed some light on it for me maybe from their experiences.

Comment: I tried EXPLAIN on those queries. All of them have the same results except for the "Extra" column. If there's a WHERE clause it will say "Using where". The interesting thing is that when I do "EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE 1 = 1" it leaves the "Extra" column empty, as if there's no WHERE clause.